# Prevent page from reload asp.net jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to do a login page with asp.net and jQuery mobile.

When the user click on the login button, I first do some processing in c# and then call the JavaScript.

The problem is that when I hit the login button, the page seems to reload before it executes the JavaScript, and I don't want that.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:Button name="login" ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
```

c#:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["username"]) != "" && String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["password"]) != "")
    {

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key", "login();", true);

    }
    else
    {
        //todo
    }

}
```

JS/jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function login() {
        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $.mobile.loading('show', {
                        text: 'Processing...',
                        textVisible: true,
                        theme: 'a'
                    });
                }, 
                type: "GET",
                url: "Handler.ashx",
                data: "method=validate",
                success: function (data) {

                    $.mobile.loading('hide');
                    //$.mobile.changePage("HomePage.aspx", { transition: "fade" });

                }
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

EDIT: I still need the server side code to deal with the password encryption that is in C#

Comment: Of course it reloads... You have to completely capture the click event in Javascript, then pass all the data to the server in AJAX.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my server side process is to encrypt the password using a class in C# :/

Comment: So is the problem that your `login` method is not getting called? From your code, it does not appear that you are calling it.

Comment: The login method is called, it's just that my login page reloads before executing the javascript, and it can be confusing for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnClick` event is a server-side event. That is why it is posting back. You want to use the `OnClientClick` event. This is for client-side code to run before the `OnClick` event is invoked.

That said, what server-side code do you need to run before calling the javascript? What exactly are you trying to do?

Please explain the process flow in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I see where is the problem now...

My process is:
When the user click on the button, server side I encrypt the password and pass it as a parameter to my javascript function.
My javascript function will then call my webservice via an handler (to bypass the cross domain conflict).

The encryption method is in a C# class.

Comment: Why do you need to call the C# function _before_ calling the handler. Can't the handler call the encryption function itself before calling the webservice?

Comment: Well I've thought about that, but I'm wondering if the password would be exposed during the ajax call to the handler?

Comment: You would face the same problem with POSTing the form values. The only way to secure that would be HTTPS.

Comment: Ok, then I think I will just do that way..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to handle the click event on the client side. `evt.preventDefault` will ensure that the button won't post back to the server.

```
$('#btnLogin').click(function(evt) {

    if(!myCondition) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
    }
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need the server side to encrypt the password using a C# class.

Comment: Interesting, I've never some across `evt.preventDefault()`. Is `evt.preventDefault()` functionally the same as using `return false;`  ?

Comment: Good discussion here: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/